# Почему js.erb файл не запускается на поддомене?

Tags: javascript, ajax, ruby-on-rails

Сделал модальное окно в виде партиала ,т.е. получил два файла вида "_modal.html.haml" и "modal.js.erb". На всех страницах без поддомена JS-код работает, на любом поддомене нет, хотя в логах вижу что все отрендерилось так же, как и в первом случае.

Где искать проблему?

Comment: В консоли браузера?

Comment: @D-side, В консоли во вкладке защита вижу "Запрос из постороннего источника заблокирован: Политика одного источника запрещает чтение удаленного ресурса. (Причина: отсутствует заголовок CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin')." Теперь понятно куда копать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Способ 1**(как подсказали опасный):

config/application.rb:

```
config.action_dispatch.default_headers.merge!({
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*',
  'Access-Control-Request-Method' => '*'
})
```

**Способ 2**(который использовал у себя):
В лейауты нужных страниц добавил рендер партиала модального окна.
Js код из js.erb вынес в js код соответствующих страниц.
Сделал второй роут на нужный action, получилось примерно так:

```
constraints(Subdomain) do
  post 'action_second/create', to: 'controller#create'
end

constraints :subdomain => '' do
  post 'action_first/create', to: 'controller#create'
end
```

P.S.

```
class Subdomain
  def self.matches?(request)
    request.subdomain.present?
  end
end
```

Comment: Ну, в общем случае это **опасно**, т. к. открывает для CSRF.